# Importing data from excel and displaying in a react component

Tags: excel, reactjs, import

I am trying to import an excel sheet with multiple columns having different set of data and display it in a react component.

Currently i am doing,

```
<ReactFileReader handleFiles={this.handleFiles} fileType={'.xlsx'}>
    <button>Import</button>
    </ReactFileReader>
```

and then

```
 handleFiles = files =>{
    var fileDisplayArea = this.refs.fileDisplayArea;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e){
    fileDisplayArea.innerHTML = reader.result;
    }
    reader.readAsText(files[0], 'utf-8');
    }
```

Although this imports the file but when rendered it displays all garbage characters. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Vikram

Comment: You're treating what is essentially a zip archive as though it's a plain text file.  That's not going to work: you need to use a library which can parse an xlsx file in a way which can be usefully rendered.

Comment: @TimWilliams: Makes sense! I guess i should parse it to JSON and then use that output to feed into a reactjs table component. Thanks a lot. Good day!

Answer (score 3):

### react-excel-renderer

There's a perfect library exactly for this ! It converts the excel data to JSON first, then renders it into a HTML table. Its called [react-excel-renderer](https://github.com/ashishd751/react-excel-renderer)

- Install it  `npm install react-excel-renderer --save`
- Import both components **ExcelRenderer** and **OutTable**

`import {ExcelRenderer, OutTable} from 'react-excel-renderer';`

- Provide the file object to the ExcelRenderer function in your event
  handler

```
      fileHandler = (event) => {
    let fileObj = event.target.files[0];

    //just pass the fileObj as parameter
    ExcelRenderer(fileObj, (err, resp) => {
      if(err){
        console.log(err);            
      }
      else{
        this.setState({
          cols: resp.cols,
          rows: resp.rows
        });
      }
    });               
    }
```

- Once JSON is obtained, provide it to the OutTable component

`<OutTable data={this.state.rows} columns={this.state.cols} tableClassName="ExcelTable2007" tableHeaderRowClass="heading" />`

Thats it ! Its done !

A demo for the same can be found [here](https://ashishd751.github.io/excel-renderer-demo/)

Comment: I see you wrote the library. Disclosure is appreciated. :)

Comment: Hi @Ashish . I have followed your steps, but it's not working for me. see the below post. Thanks