# Integrating django-import-export with react

Tags: django, reactjs, database, django-import-export

I have a postgresql database and I want to add data to it.
I want to upload an excel file containing the data and save it to database.
I have a backend server of django and a frontend server of React.
I am easily able to import the data from the excel sheet to database using django_import_export but from the django admin.
What I want is, to do this using React and for normal users(non superusers) also. Is there a way to integrate django_import_export with react? Any other way to implement this functionality is also apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your backend uses a REST API to handle requests from the frontend.  So, you can write an API handler which receives the [Excel data posted to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51084434/how-to-upload-an-excel-sheet-file-using-react-js-and-display-data-to-a-table).

The Django API handler can create an import process to handle upload.  Check the [documentation](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) for more information.

Note that if you are loading large files, then you might want to handle the upload asychronously.  This is little more tricky, but you could look at [Celery](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/celery.html) to help with this.